# How to make C# Application without setup Package

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, portability

I want need for the `Winforms` application to be installed. For that I am setting `Copy Local` to true for MY referenced dlls. I build My project and copy all the files in `/Bin/Release` or `/Bin/Debug` (as my project settings).

But Problem is I have to installed on the client's machine is the appropriate .Net Framework version.

is there any option to  Winforms application to be run on the client's machine without .Net Framework installation. So I can copy in USB Drive and run it any where,

Comment: No.  You have to have the proper .NET framework installed otherwise the program won't run.

Comment: Not really, but everything since XP has had some version pre-installed (or installed on first use).  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **No**.

However, as you can see from the [Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx), if you are using a Microsoft Windows Version that is still supported, you have very good chances of having a Framework Version 3.0 or 3.5 preinstalled and already available.